# How to show Java Dependency (to add external jar) in vscode?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, quarkus

I am working on Quarkus application in vscode and we want to add external jars to that application, I have seen few demos but in my project "Java Dependencies" tab is not there, how to show it?

[image][image]

Please Help me out as I am new to it.

This "Java Dependencies" tab is not visible in my above project.

Answer (score 0):

Click your project under **JAVA PROJECTS**, click **+** to add Maven Dependencies:

[image]

Detailed information please view [Project Management in vscode-java: Add a dependency](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_add-a-dependency)

Comment: I want to add external jar not maven dependencies like below:https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_add-a-jar

Comment: umm..There's no such buttons to add jars in **Maven** Project. You can put the jar in your local repository and quote it in pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

[image: VSCode Image]

I know this is really late; I stumbled here when trying to solve this problem myself. Now that I have found the solution, I am sharing on this for anyone coming this way later so, here goes: You can simply click on the '+' button to add external JARs (see in the screenshot).